# What's the equivalent of react-native-svg rotation with origins using react-native animated api

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-svg

I'm having below svg path, which rotates around origin in every `value` state change successfully, where value is some degrees value:

```
<Path
   transform={{
      rotation: this.state.value,
      originX: width / 2,
      originY: height / 2
   }}
   d={`M ${width * 0.5} ${height * 0.5} L${width * 0.75} ${height * 0.75}`} //the actual path does not matter 
   fill={Colors.black}
   stroke={Colors.black}
   />
```

I call setState on the `value` every ~20 ms, but this is not smooth enough, + it's not the recommended way of doing a transition.
What i want to achieve, is animate the rotation using the animated API, to achieve much smoother rotation.

I have tried making my `value` state an `Animated.Value`. Then making the `Path` a `Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path)` and calling:

```
Animated.timing(this.state.value, {
    toValue: newDegreesValue,
    duration: 1000,
    useNativeDriver: true
}).start();
```

Then i render the path like this:

```
<Path
   style={transform:[{
      rotate: this.state.value
   }]}
   d={`M ${width * 0.5} ${height * 0.5} L${width * 0.75} ${height * 0.75}`} //the actual path does not matter 
   fill={Colors.black}
   stroke={Colors.black}
   />
```

This doesn't work at all close to the previously working code using state. One reason is the originX, originY values that are not supported by the animation API and i don't know how to replace, but I'm not sure it's the only reason, maybe `rotate` is somehow different than `rotation` property too?. 
So, the question is, how can the same outcome by the code which is continuously calling setState be achieved using animated api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way i achieved it:

```
// init the animatedComponents
const NeedlePath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path);
const AnimatedG = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(G);

// set the animation
Animated.timing(this.state.angle, {
        toValue: 240, // degrees
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();

// pivotX and pivotY are the originX, originY points.
// the width and height are calculated dynamically, so that the whole svg is a square (equal height width), and the center of it are my origins.
render() {
    let height = this.state.height;
    let width = this.state.width;
    let [pivotX, pivotY] = [0, 0];
    if (height && width) {
        [pivotX, pivotY] = [width / 2, height / 2];
    }
   return (
        <View
            style={{ flex: 1}}
            onLayout={event => {
                this.findDimesions(event.nativeEvent.layout); // find height and width dynamically, so that this remain a square container with same height and width
            }}
        >
            {height !== undefined && width !== undefined && (
                <Svg height={height} width={width} style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                   <G transform={`translate(${pivotX}, ${pivotY})`}>
                        <AnimatedG
                            style={{
                                transform: [
                                    {
                                        rotate: this.state.angle.interpolate({
                                            inputRange: [0, 360],
                                            outputRange: [`0deg`, `360deg`]
                                        })
                                    }
                                ]
                            }}
                        >
                            <NeedlePath
                                transform={`translate(-${pivotX} -${pivotY})`}
                                d={`M ${width * 0.5} ${height * 0.5} L${width * 0.5 + width * 0.25} ${height * 0.5 + height * 0.25}`}
                                fill={Colors.black}
                                stroke={Colors.black}
                            />
                        </AnimatedG>
                    </G>
                </Svg>
            )}
        </View>
    );
}
```

The `style={{ alignItems: "center" }}` is crucial to achieve the same result on android too, instead of setting translationX and translationY with offsetAndroid. This is working for version `v9.13.3` of react-native-svg. Maybe in newer versions this get affected, because of fixing the translations problem, and i don't know what the impact will be on the code here. You can refer [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/1248) for more info about the translations with offset needed on android

Answer (score 0):

you need use interpolate

```
const animation=this.state.value.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 360],
  outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
});
<Path
   style={transform:[{
      rotate:animation
   }]}
```

Comment: But what about origins?

Comment: In the past I looked for such an option and did not find one